# Azure Datafactory Upload to Salesforce and reference field on another object

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory, salesforce-lightning

This is the scenario - we are using Azure DataFactoryV2 to run a series of pipelines that take account data from a local datasource, transform it and upload into Salesforce.

Currently we are wanting to Import an Account and relate it to another account. There is the standard Parent/Child relationship for Accounts (eg a Reseller account and a child account) and this is using the internal Salesforce ID.

We are also using an External ID for the purpose of Upserting and this ID is unique to each record.

According to SF Documentation: [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm) - when you manually call the API and pass it a JSON file, you are able to add a relationship within the JSON:

```
    {
   "Name" : "NewAccount",
   "account__r" :
   {
       "Ext_UID__c" : 123
   }

}
```

However, this doesn't appear to be doable in Azure DataFactoryV2 to specify a lookup relationship in the code, or if it is, I'm not sure how to do it.

For reference - here is the Pipeline JSON code:

```
{
"name": "Import_to_Salesforce",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Load_to_Salesforce",
            "type": "Copy",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "[dbo].[Account]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Destination",
                    "value": "Account"
                }
            ],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlSource"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SalesforceSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 5000,
                    "writeBehavior": "upsert",
                    "externalIdFieldName": "Ext_UID__c",
                    "ignoreNullValues": false
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
                "dataIntegrationUnits": 0,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "columnMappings": {
                        "Name": "Name",
                        "ParentId": "ParentId",
                        "BillingStreet": "BillingStreet",
                        "BillingCity": "BillingCity",
                        "BillingPostalCode": "BillingPostalCode",
                        "BillingCountry": "BillingCountry",
                        "ShippingStreet": "ShippingStreet",
                        "ShippingCity": "ShippingCity",
                        "ShippingPostalCode": "ShippingPostalCode",
                        "ShippingCountry": "ShippingCountry",
                        "Phone": "Phone",
                        "AccountNumber": "AccountNumber",
                        "Brand__c": "Brand__c",
                        "Account_Status__c": "Account_Status__c",
                        "Account_Type__c": "Account_Type__c",
                        "Preferred_Payment_Method__c": "Preferred_Payment_Method__c",
                        "Last_Account_Login__c": "Last_Account_Login__c",
                        "Ext_UID__c": "Ext_UID__c",
                        "Auto_Renew_Status__c": "Auto_Renew_Status__c",
                        "Account_Balance__c": "Account_Balance__c",
                        "Outstanding_Amount_30_days__c": "Outstanding_Amount_30_days__c",
                        "Outstanding_Amount_60_days__c": "Outstanding_Amount_60_days__c",
                        "Outstanding_Amount_90_days__c": "Outstanding_Amount_90_days__c",
                        "Account_Priority__c": "Account_Priority__c",
                        "Reseller__c": "Reseller__c",
                        "Last_Payment__c": "Last_Payment__c"
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Staging_Source",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Destination_Load_to_Salesforce",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which SF connector you're using? If there's no meaningful name look at your API user's login history in Salesforce. It's probably listed as "Simba Technologies" or something like that?

For standard relationships you should be able to just type <strike>`Account.Ext_UID__c`</strike> `Parent.Ext_UID__c`like in this Contact load:

[image]

For custom lookups/master-detail fields if the field API name is `Account__c` you can map it for upsert as `Account__r.Ext_UID__c`.

Just make sure that parent accounts exist before child accounts reference them... Maybe you loaded them in previous job, maybe it's best to load it in two stages:

1. Flat insert/upsert of all accounts without parent mapped
2. Reparenting update/upsert that maps only this record's ext id and the parent's ext. id

Comment: You, Sir, Are a Scholar and a Gentleman! That worked like an absolute Charm!

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm just "lucky" that I had to help my colleague investigate it recently. I'm not impressed with that connector to be honest. It's 1 year old API version (doesn't see `Individual` table in SF database for example), doesn't let you specify batch size (how many records at a time you want to load) or API type (this is SOAP, bit less secure than REST + OAuth2. Plus ideally I'd have option to use SF bulk API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/introduction_bulk_api_2.htm). hopefully they improve the plugin soon.

Comment: This answer was so useful! NB: If you're doing this with an External ID that is sometimes blank (i.e. an optional lookup relationship where sometimes there is no related object) you need to pass an empty string rather than a NULL or an #N/A - otherwise Bulk API complains about MISSING_ARGUMENT

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Activity is available in ADF v2:

[image: Lookup Activity in ADF v2]

Here you can select the dataset and the row at which you want to lookup.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - but doing a Lookup is only querying the Salesforce Object, to return the Salesforce ID, which we would then need to store somewhere and map onto our existing object - which is not what we are after. We're looking to use the existing native functionality of the SF API, from within ADFv2