# Copy data from Azure SQL Server to Salesforce using Azure Data Factory

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I am new to Azure Data Factory and trying to solve a business use case where our data is stored in Azure Blob Storage which needs to be copied into Salesforce using Azure Data Factory. I have done a lot of research on this but all the examples I got are for copying data from Salesforce to SQL Server using Azure Data Factory.

So far I have been able to get the access token from Salesforce by using Web Activity in Azure Data Factory and then connecting that Web Activity to another Web Activity that would copy Bulk Data into Salesforce using SF Bulk API. But for some reason when the activity tries to read the CSV file stored in Azure Blob Storage it is giving me the following error:

[image]

Below is my pipeline which fails when the second web activity runs:

[image: Settings(2)]
[image: Settings]

Below is the screenshot of my csv file:
[image: CSV]

It would be really helpful if anyone has any idea why can't azure pipeline read my csv file and how can I resolve this error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's been over 3 years ago and I don't work with that client anymore. But look into Azure Data Factory 2... plugins? Connectors? Marketplace? Whatever is the right name. There should be 1-2 plugins for connecting to Salesforce. It was pretty easy to use, even for me who knows nothing about Azure ecosystem. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53623673/313628

Comment: @eyescream Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

Comment: Hi @Mariya, not very clear for your  pipeline. Why don't you use copy active to copy the csv file to sink salesforce database? I don't suggestion you using Web active.