# How to query the Salesforce Case object from inside ADF

Tags: sql, t-sql, salesforce, azure-data-factory, soql

In ADF using the Copy activity, I have a parameterized query to copy data from Salesforce.

```
SELECT * FROM @{item().object_name} WHERE CreatedDate > '@{formatDateTime(item().last_run_time,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}'
```

I have no issues with other object names until it comes to the Case object. ADF mistakes this Case object as a TSQL keyword. I have tried encapsulating the item in single quotes, double quotes, and square brackets. All have failed. I have tried setting the object_name as a variable and passing that over and it fails. I've tried passing over the variable with single quotes, double quotes, and square brackets and it all still fails.

Comment: How are you connecting? Been few years since I had to do ADF -> SF but back then there was a free marketplace plugin by "Simba Technologies" and it didn't have problems with Case. If there's a more native solution now (but it can't deal with this 1 table...) Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626425/313628? Not really an answer, more how to check what you're using / give this other one a go. https://insightsoftware.com/drivers/salesforce-odbc-jdbc/ (not affiliated in any way)

Comment: You are querying sql server right? Not Salesforce? Because `select *` wont work in Salesforce. For SQL Server you could try adding the schema? e.g. `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Case] ... `

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM @{concat("'", item().object_name, "'")} WHERE CreatedDate > '@{formatDateTime(item().last_run_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}'
```